# Programatically converting from MS word to Excel

Tags: excel, automation, ms-word, ms-office

Is there anyway to problematically take a MS Word file and convert to excel. (Obviously, word would to guess where to put stuff).  Any language would be fine

Comment: For the purpose of your question, is it okay to assume that both Word and Excel are installed on the machine running the code?

Comment: Can you provide an example of what are you trying to accomplish ? I can understand transfering tables, or pictures ... but this is pretty wide question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a pretty wide-open question.  The content of the Word document will affect how easy/hard this is.

One method you could look at is using Word automation to open the Word document and then write out a new file using comma-separated format and just name the file with a .xls extension.  Upon opening this file up in Excel it should "just work".

If you need rich formatting in your output Excel document, you could use Excel automation to build your output document.  Using this you'd have both Word automation (read) and Excel automation (write) in your program.

Another option that I've used (but it's a bit pricey) in a server environment is the Aspose libraries [Aspose](http://www.aspose.com).  They have a pretty nice API (at least for Word, which is what I've used) and they eliminate the automation angle.

Answer (score 1):

See http://blogs.msdn.com/brian_jones/archive/2009/04/01/importing-a-table-from-wordprocessingml-to-spreadsheetml.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Here is a resource on automating office applications: [Office Object Models](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y1xatbkd(VS.80).aspx)