# Displaying Tables from a document in a WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, interop

I am working on a small application which reads through the word document and analyze it. The data present in the document are present in the form of tables ,Is there any way to display the data(tabular data) in the application..?
If DGV is the only solution for displaying a table ,Is there any way to bind the Interop table to Datagrid

Comment: How does this interop table look like? DataGridView is not the only way to display table data, but it's probably the best idea if you only use stock controls. But both Telerik and Infragistics has custom Grid Views which are much better and more customizable. http://www.telerik.com/products/wpf/gridview.aspx http://www.infragistics.com/products/wpf/grid/

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this would be the best approach but this is what I came up with right now. Google shows that there are many solutions to bind Excel to a DataGridView but hardly any for Word. In fact Stack Overflow also has many answers on converting Word to Excel.

Therefore, why not convert the Word contents to Excel and then bind the Excel contents to DGV? It's a roundabout way I know, but something is better than nothing. Here are some links that may help in this regard:

[Programatically converting from MS word to Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/698410/programatically-converting-from-ms-word-to-excel)

[Display excel file content in a Datagridview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7315782/display-excel-file-content-in-a-datagridview)

http://www.dotneter.com/reading-excel-and-binding-to-datagridview-using-microsoft-office-interop-excel

[Transferring data from Excel to dataGridView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8206418/transfering-data-from-excel-to-datagridview?rq=1)

Comment: Good Thought ..!! I am waiting for someone to give a better approach. If not i will accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

If its just a matter of displaying then directly display the *`Word`* document in you WPF application.
Here, the [***link***](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mahesh/viewing-word-documents-in-wpf/) to achieve this.

Comment: Certainly not.. If there some to display only the required part of the document then this method could be useful.